# How to solve the Profit and loss problem?

Tags: arithmetic

**Problem:** A shop keeper prices p toys at Rs. q per toy. If the cost of each toy is increased by Rs. r, then find how much more money will be earned by the shop owner after selling p toys?​

**Effort :** Let the Old cost price of each toy be Rs. $x$. Then Selling price of each toy is Rs. $q $ $(>x)$. New  cost price of each toy is Rs. $x+r$. New cost price of $p$ toys is Rs. $p(x+r)$ and the selling price of $p$ toys is Rs. $pq$.
I am stuck here. By the way is my approach correct?

**Updated:**
Old cost of each toy is Rs. $q$.
Old cost of $p$ toys is Rs. $pq$.
The cost of each toy is increased by Rs. $r$. So the new cost of each toy becomes  $q+r$.
The new cost of $p$ toys is Rs. $p(q+r)$.
After selling $p$ toys, the shop keeper  will  earn Rs. $p(q+r)-pq=pr$.

Comment: I think "cost of each toy" here means the amount the shopkeeper receives (i.e. the price $q$ and later $q+r$) not the amount the shopkeeper pays

Comment: @Henry Thank you very much for your correction. You will solve the problem please?

Comment: How much would the shopkeeper receive at the old price?  How much would the shopkeeper receive at the new price? How much is the difference?

Comment: Surely the problem is *almost* ambiguous, but the only way the shopkeeper will earn *more* money ("how much **more** money?") is if *they* increased the price of the toy, not if the cost they pay for the toys increased. (That would bring them *less* money.)

Comment: The shopkeeper appears to earning $pq-p(x+r)=p(q-x-r)$. If this is not what you mean please let us know more precisely what is required.